# Como utilizar una clase como tipo de una funcion externa a la clase?

Tags: c++, funciones, clase

Como utilisar un tipo de una clase dentre de una función externa a la clase ?

Por ejemplo vamos a utilizar de esta ejemplo de matematicas. Quiero crear una clase abtracta `Bola` con dos atributos y una función `contiene` que me dice si un punto `PuntoRn` esta en una bola :

```
class Bola{ 

    private:
        int dim;
        double* adr;

    public: 
        bool contiene(PuntoRn p);
        virtual void Message() = 0;
}; 

class PuntoRn{

    public:
        PuntoRn(int dim, double* adr);
        PuntoRn(const PointRn &);
            // Comment fait on un destructeur ?
        ~PuntoRn(){
            cout << "Destructor de PuntoRn.\n";
        }


    private:
        int dim;
        double* adr;

};

int main(){
    PointRn pa = PointRn(2,0);

    pa = {0,0};

}
```

Sin embargo, el terminal me dice

```
error: ‘PointRn’ has not been declared
   bool contient(PointRn p);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> El terminal me dice
>
> ```
> error: ‘PointRn’ has not been declared
>    bool contient(PointRn p);
> ```

Y ese es el problema; el tipo `PointRn` no ha sido declarado.

#### Declaración.

En C++ (y varios otros lenguajes) hasta que no se declara un tipo, el tipo no existe. ¿Cómo se declara un tipo?:

> `[class / struct / union / enum ] nombre ;`

En cuanto aparece una palabra clave de tipo, como por ejemplo `class` seguida del nombre del tipo, por ejemplo `PointRn`, consideramos que el tipo está declarado: le estamos diciendo al compilador:

- *Existe un tipo llamado `PointRn` que posiblemente **use más adelante***.

Lo de **más adelante** es muy importante, las declaraciones se leen de ↑ arriba a ↓ abajo. Así que si queremos usar un tipo, debemos haberlo declarado en **líneas anteriores**. Por lo tanto, en tu código:

```
/* 01 */ class Bola{ 
/* 02 */ 
/* 03 */     private:
/* 04 */         int dim;
/* 05 */         double* adr;
/* 06 */ 
/* 07 */     public: 
/* 08 */         bool contiene(PuntoRn p);
/* 09 */         virtual void Message() = 0;
/* 10 */ };
```

En la línea 8 estás usando un tipo llamado `PuntoRn` que no ha sido declarado en ninguna línea anterior, para solucionarlo tienes dos soluciones:

#### Primera opción: Cambiar el orden de declaración.

```
class PuntoRn{
    public:
        PuntoRn(int dim, double* adr);
        PuntoRn(const PuntoRn &);
        // Comment fait on un destructeur ?
        ~PuntoRn(){
            std::cout << "Destructor de PuntoRn.\n";
        }

    private:
        int dim;
        double* adr;
};

class Bola{ 
    private:
        int dim;
        double* adr;

    public: 
        bool contiene(PuntoRn p);
        virtual void Message() = 0;
};
```

Podrás ver que ahora le decimos al compilador que `PuntoRn` existe antes de que sea usado como parámetro en `Bola::contiene(PuntoRn)`.

#### Segunda opción: Pre-declaración.

C++ permite separar la declaración de un tipo de la definición del tipo. La declaración ya hemos visto cómo se hace:

```
// class nombre;
class PuntoRn;
```

Con eso avisamos al compilador de que existe un tipo con el nombre `PuntoRn`, pero no le decimos nada más: no hemos indicado cómo está compuesto, no hemos escrito ninguna función miembro ni variables miembro... en resumen: no lo hemos definido. Pero pese a no estar definido, al estar declarado puede usarse en algunos contextos:

```
/* 01 */ class PuntoRn; // Declaración de PuntoRn
/* 02 */ 
/* 03 */ class Bola{ 
/* 04 */ 
/* 05 */     private:
/* 06 */         int dim;
/* 07 */         double* adr;
/* 08 */
/* 09 */     public: 
/* 10 */         bool contiene(PuntoRn p); // Uso de PuntoRn
/* 11 */         virtual void Message() = 0;
/* 12 */ };
/* 13 */
/* 14 */ class PuntoRn{  // Definición de PuntoRn
/* -- */ ...
/* 22 */ };
```

Declarar un tipo y usarlo sin definirlo, se conoce en C++ como *Pre-declaración* (forward declaration en Inglés). La Pre-declaración permite usar el tipo sin haberlo definido, siempre y cuando el tipo no se instancie.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Bola{ 

    private:
        int dim;
        double* adr;

    public: 
        bool contiene(PuntoRn p);
        virtual void Message() = 0;
};
```

El compilador va a coger esa clase y va a procesarla para generar código binario. Para que dicho código sea válido el compilador necesita tener información suficiente sobre los tipos que se usan. ¿Qué es `PuntoRn`? ¿Es un objeto? ¿un alias quizás? ¿un puntero a función? Como la declaración de `PuntoRn` es **posterior** a la declaración de la función `contiene()` el compilador no puede resolver el problema y te da un error de compilación.

Para solucionar el problema puedes recurrir a las *declaration forward* o declaraciones adelantadas:

```
class PuntoRn; // declaration forward

class Bola{ 

    private:
        int dim;
        double* adr;

    public: 
        bool contiene(PuntoRn p);
        virtual void Message() = 0;
};
```

Ahora el compilador no se va a quejar porque ya sabe que `PuntoRn` es una clase y es todo lo que necesita saber por el momento.

En la implementación de la función la cosa cambia. En este punto, y dado que estás usando `PuntoRn` por valor, el compilador necesitará conocer la interfaz de `PuntoRn` para poder resolver correctamente las dependencias. Esto lo puedes resolver con un `#include`:

Bola.cpp

```
#include "PuntoRn.h" // o donde se encuentre la declaración

bool Bola::contiene(PuntoRn p)
{
  // ...
}
```

También puedes, como ha comentado @Trauma, cambiar el orden de las declaraciones pero esa operativa no va a funcionar cuando tienes una dependencia mutua:

```
class A
{
  void func1(B);
};

class B
{
  void func2(A);
};
```

¿Cual colocas primero? En cualquiera de los dos casos vas a tener un error de compilación, mientras que con *declaration forward* la solución es trivial.

```
class B;

class A
{
  void func1(B);
};

class B
{
  void func2(A);
};
```